# Cannot debug NDK. Strange error

Tags: android, android-ndk, ubuntu-12.04

I ran the NDK project then type the command. It generates the error. I don't know how to fix it.

This is the command.

```
hieund@hieund:~/Programs/AndroidNDK/samples/hello-gl2$ $NDK_HOME/ndk-gdb
/home/hieund/Programs/AndroidNDK/build/core/build-local.mk:40: build/core/init.mk: No such file or directory
/home/hieund/Programs/AndroidNDK/build/core/build-local.mk:166: /add-application.mk: No such file or directory
/home/hieund/Programs/AndroidNDK/build/core/build-local.mk:174: /setup-imports.mk: No such file or directory
/home/hieund/Programs/AndroidNDK/build/core/build-local.mk:191: /build-all.mk: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `/build-all.mk'.  Stop.
ERROR: The device does not support the application's targetted CPU ABIs!
       Device supports:  armeabi-v7a armeabi
       Package supports:
```

I checked the make's version, it's ok.

```
hieund@hieund:~/Programs/AndroidNDK/samples/hello-gl2$ make -version
GNU Make version 3.75, by Richard Stallman and Roland McGrath.
Copyright (C) 1988, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96
    Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Report bugs to <bug-gnu-utils@prep.ai.mit.edu>.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is ndk-gdb can't find the latest make. This command fixed the problem:

```
export GNUMAKE=/usr/bin/make
```

Answer (score 1):

`The device does not support the application's targetted CPU ABIs!` you are building a library which is not supported by your device. Check your devices `CPU ABI`

```
String abi=Build.CPU_ABI;
Toast.makeText(CpuinfoActivity.this, "CPU ABI is :::"+abi, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

`ndk-gdb` expects certain environment on Linux. I run it as follows:

```
 >ANDROID_NDK_ROOT=/etc/android-ndk-r8b GNUMAKE=/etc/android-ndk-r8b/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/make ndk-gdb
```

You can use `/usr/bin/make` if you prefer.